# Dynamic link is not working after email sent (gmail, outlook..etc)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, dynamic

We have built a dynamic link for subscriber,
below is script and html i used

```
    SET @Mid = field(@row,"Meeting_id") Set @FURL = CONCAT('http://www.abc.fr/xyz/meetings/v3/','?meetingId=',@Mid)


     <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="%%=v(@FURL)=%%" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title=""><span style="color: #F6C136; text-decoration: underline;">Subscribe</span></a>
```

Link is working fine in ET tool, when i do test send with my gmail, outlook...etcam that time link is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your situation I can predict that you have two options which could work.

**Option 1:**

With your current code, if you disable the option `Track all links in this email` then the link will work on both send preview and actual email send. But you will lose the tracking functionality for that link.

[image: Disable tracking url]

**Option 2:**

If you enable the option `Track all links in this email` then you're only missing a **[RedirectTo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm)** function in your href.This function only provides tracking information for clickable links within an email message. And I guess you'd probably have this option enabled in your test send and  when you're sending the email, sfmc is generating unique tracking links which gets masked on top of original link and they won't work without **[RedirectTo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm)** function.

Here is your revised code:

```
SET @Mid = field(@row,"Meeting_id") Set @FURL = CONCAT('http://www.abc.fr/xyz/meetings/v3/','?meetingId=',@Mid)

<a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="%%=RedirectTo(@FURL)=%%" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" title=""><span style="color: #F6C136; text-decoration: underline;">Subscribe</span></a>
```